# Sending files from and to Virtualbox images

Tags: virtualbox

In VmWare, transferring a file from host to guest was a simple as dragging it from your explorer onto the VmWare screen.

In Virtualbox, you have to set up shared folders.

I've set one up, yet I cannot find anything on my guest host(Windows 7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run Windows Explorer in a Windows 7 VirtualBox machine.

Type the following into the address bar to access the shared folder:

```
\\vboxsvr\<Shared Folder Name>
```

For a more permanent solution create a new shortcut with the same target.

[image]

Of course you'll have to change 'shared' to the name of your shared folder, it just happened to be the name I chose.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I had to test it out. It works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: you're more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up an FTP server on host or guest for this purpose (assuming they are already interconnected).